# Little to no mouse settings - 13.04

Tags: mouse

Ok so I can't post a pic yet so this should be fun.

On my mouse settings I only have 2 settings.

Primary Button   (.) Left     ( ) Right

Double Click    Slow----------|-----------Fast

That's it. No speed or accel. or anything else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this annoying issue by installing Pointing Settings from the Software Center.
Or you can run

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

from the command line.